# Two ReactJS apps in single page

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to have two React apps in single page.

e.g. Two panels:

- Left panel: ReactJS app A
- Right panel: ReactJS app B

**UPDATE**

I am sorry. May be phrased it the wrong way. But I am new to ReactJS and I use the wrong terms. These two apps might be independent. Created by 2 different people not aware of each other. They will not share code.

Like facebook social box with like button and people faces who liked page and same twitter box.

I think it is bit different and two react dom calls create a single new add that attach to two different nodes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is.

Just use a few `ReactDOM.render()`:

```
ReactDom.render('appA', document.getElementById('#selector_for_app_a'))
ReactDom.render('appB', document.getElementById('#selector_for_app_b'))
```

**UPDATE**

Since you slightly modified your question, my answer is going to be modified as well.

Just ask two separate developers to write a code which ends up with lines specified above. First line for the first developed app, second line for second developed app.

You could easily specify where to place embed widgets in your html then, just add `<div id="selector_for_app_a"></div>` & `<div id="selector_for_app_b"></div>` correspondingly

Comment: May be I asked that the wrong way. I wish to put two independent React apps. Source code of each app is not dependent on other.

Comment: It's not dependent on each other on the way I answered

Comment: Yes. My bad. I add UPDATE to my question

Comment: Added UPDATE to my answer as well ;)